# Swagger Dropwizard 0.7 - TextArea for JSON parameter not displayed

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, swagger, dropwizard

### The problem

I can't find the reason Swagger doesn't show the POST end point with the textarea 'body' available so I can paste JSON into.

I expected to see a page like this the POST in [PetStore Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.io/)

But my form is simply posted after I click 'Try it out' and I get

### Response Body

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Error 415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
      </head>
      <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 415</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /promotions. Reason:
          <pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
      </body>
    </html>
```

### Response Headers

```
{
  "access-control-allow-origin": "http://localhost:8080",
  "date": "Thu, 11 Jun 2015 07:37:15 GMT",
  "cache-control": "must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store",
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "content-type": "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
  "content-length": "320",
  "access-control-expose-headers": ""
}
```

Can you help me with this please?

### More information on my project

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

**Maven**

```
parent
    - pom.xml:   <dropwizard.version>0.8.1</dropwizard.version>
                 <swagger.version>0.7.0</swagger.version>)
  app
    - pom.xml:   <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                 </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.federecio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
                    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
                 </dependency>
    - config.yml: 
                 swagger:
                   resourcePackage: myproject.promotion.v1.resource             
  representation
    - pom.xml
```

**Configuration**

```
package myproject.promotion.app.config;

public class PromotionServiceConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @JsonProperty("swagger")
    public SwaggerBundleConfiguration swaggerBundleConfiguration;
```

}

**Application**

```
package myproject.promotion.app;

public class PromotionServiceApplication extends Application<PromotionServiceConfiguration> {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new PromotionServiceApplication().run(args);
}

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<PromotionServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new PromotionSwaggerBundle());
}

@Override
public void run(PromotionServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
//Deleted to make it short
}
```

}

**PromotionSwaggerBundle**

```
package myproject.promotion.app.config;

public class PromotionSwaggerBundle extends SwaggerBundle<PromotionServiceConfiguration> {

@Override
protected SwaggerBundleConfiguration getSwaggerBundleConfiguration(PromotionServiceConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration.swaggerBundleConfiguration;
}
```

}

**End point**

```
package myproject.v1.resource;

@Path("/promotions")
@Api(value = "/promotions/", description = "Promotions' possible operations", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class PromotionManagementResource {

    private static final String PROMO_PARAM = "promotionId";

    private final PromotionManagementService promotionManagementService;

    @Inject
    public PromotionManagementResource(PromotionManagementService promotionManagementService) {
        this.promotionManagementService = promotionManagementService;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create promotion")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Promotion created. Link to it in Location HEADER"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Promotion already exists")
            })
    public Response create(final Promotion promotion, @Context final UriInfo uriInfo) throws IOException {
        Promotion createdPromotion = promotionManagementService.create(promotion);

        URI createdInventoryURI = inventory(createdPromotion, uriInfo);
        return Response.created(createdInventoryURI).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the annotation [@ApiParam](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apiparam) did the trick.

**New POST method (with the new annotation)**

```
@POST
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Create promotion", notes = "", response = Promotion.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Promotion created. Link to it in Location HEADER."),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Promotion already exist.")
})
public Response create(@ApiParam final Promotion promotion, @Context final UriInfo uriInfo) throws IOException {
    Promotion createdPromotion = promotionManagementService.create(promotion);

    URI createdPromotionURI = uriTo(createdPromotion, uriInfo);
    return Response.created(createdPromotionURI).build();
}
```

Thanks for your help cyrbil.

Answer (score 0):

You have `@Api` as a decorator with `consumes = "application/json"`, and your error is about `Unsupported Media Type`.
So your endpoint expect that you send application/json post data, your browser sends `multipart/form-data` or url encoded data.

Comment: I tried the following combinations but still get 415

    `@Api(value = "/promotions/", description = "Promotions' possible operations", consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = "multipart/form-data")`

and 

    `@Api(value = "/promotions/", description = "Promotions' possible operations")`

Comment: You are taking it from the wrong part, your browser need to send it as application/json. You can do it with [ajax (and jquery for easier use)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or with plugins ([1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn),[2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop),[3](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)...)

Comment: Swagger is deployed on the '/swagger' context which has a script that loads its own UI. This UI automatically loads the generated 'swagger.json' from my own environment and renders the available operations.
I used the plugins you mentioned and the app works as expected. But 'Swagger UI' doesn't recognise POST and this started happening from version 0.7.x

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Within the `ApiOperation` decorator, you can specify `httpMethod`. see [doc here](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.html) for details.